# Find exact string in element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of span elements inside a container and I want to match the exact word of one of the spans to insert a banner. I cant figure out how to do this.

First i tried this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($('.head.titlebox span').text().trim() === "match" ){
 $('<span class="myAwesomeBanner4"></span>').insertAfter(".productbox em.price.product-card-price")
 }
else if ($('.head.titlebox span').text().trim() === "matchother" ){
$('<span class="myAwesomeBanner5"></span>').insertAfter(".productbox em.price.product-card-price")
}
});
```

This doesnt work - unless I remove the string it should match: === "". So the script seems kike it kinda works. I cant match it to the words though - looks like its correct to me, so not sure why it's not working.

Then I tried this script which works - but I cant figure out how to convert it to use if statement and to create my div to insert in the DOM like above:

```
$('.head.titlebox span').filter(function(index) { 
return $(this).text() === "match";}).css("background", "black");
```

My HTML for targeting the string:

```
<div class="head titlebox">
 <span id="artid">text</span><h1 id="prod-title">text</h1>
 <span>text</span><span>text</span>
 <span>match</span>
</div>
```

So why is the first not working - and how do I combine it with the working filter function of the second script?

Comment: You need to use `each` to iterate over all the elements

Comment: Do you want to only insert one banner, or potentially both?

Comment: Right - `.text()` returns the text of the first element matched by the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through all the span tags,

```
$('.head.titlebox span').each(function() {
   if ($(this).text() == "match") {
      //insert your html.
   }
})
```

Comment: Please use "===" instead of "=="

Comment: Aah. Thanks! Makes sense :p

Comment: Also, Javascript provides .match() method to compare strings. Might be a [better alternative](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) to use :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$(".head").on("click", function() {
  var spanList = $(".head span");
  $.each(spanList,function(span){
      console.log($(spanList[span]).text());
      if($(spanList[span]).text() === "match"){
       console.log("Matched")
      }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head titlebox">
  <span id="artid">text</span>
  <h1 id="prod-title">text</h1>
  <span>text</span><span>text</span>
  <span>match</span>
</div>
```